# JAVA - No entra en el switch, probablemente por no saber escribirlo correctamente

Tags: java

Tengo una duda. Estoy empezando con Java y no sé si al realizar este ejercicio para calcular el coste del agua en función de su consumo no he indicado bien al programa para que se meta en el switch o dónde se encuentra el fallo.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
package consumo.de.agua;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConsumoDeAgua {

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out. print ("Dime el consumo de agua: ");
   int consumoAgua = sc.nextInt();
   int value=0;
   
   switch (sc.nextInt(4)){
    case 0: consumoAgua > 0 && consumoAgua <=100;
            value = consumoAgua*0.15;
            break;
    case 1: consumoAgua > 100 && consumoAgua <=500;
            value = consumoAgua*0.20;
            break;
    case 2: consumoAgua > 500 && consumoAgua <=1000;
            value = consumoAgua*0.35;
            break;
    case 3: consumoAgua >1000;
            value = consumoAgua*0.80;
            break;
    default: consumoAgua = 0;
  }
   System.out.print("El coste de tu consumo es de:" + "consumoAgua" + "€");
   }    
}
```

¿Me podríais ayudar?.

Gracias.

Comment: Tengo dos dudas, la primera es que el profesor dice que cuando hay más de 3 IFS anidados, mejor hacer un switch. La segunda, en ”int consumoAgua = 0sc.nextInt();" entiendo que falta un punto y coma...o algo,no?(no lo entiendo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa la lógica de tu programa.  En vez de `switch (sc.nextInt(4))` debería ser `switch(consumoAgua)`.

Aunque también deberías revisar esta parte, ya que la declaración de sentencias no es correcta:

```
case 0: consumoAgua > 0 && consumoAgua <=100;
            value = consumoAgua*0.15;
            break;
    case 1: consumoAgua > 100 && consumoAgua <=500;
            value = consumoAgua*0.20;
            break;
    case 2: consumoAgua > 500 && consumoAgua <=1000;
            value = consumoAgua*0.35;
            break;
    case 3: consumoAgua >1000;
            value = consumoAgua*0.80;
            break;
```

Mucho cuidado a la hora de trabajar con tipos int y tipos double:

```
value = consumoAgua*0.15;
```

Esto te causará un problema de conversión, ya que declaraste value como int, pero la operación devuelve un valor double.

Una versión de tu programa puede ser:

```
package programa;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConsumoDeAgua{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Dime el consumo de agua: ");
    int consumoAgua = 0sc.nextInt();
    double value=0;

    
    
    if(consumoAgua > 0 && consumoAgua <=100){
      value = consumoAgua*0.15;
    }
            
    if(consumoAgua > 100 && consumoAgua <=500){
      value = consumoAgua*0.20;
    }
            
    if(consumoAgua > 500 && consumoAgua <=1000){
      value = consumoAgua*0.35;
    }
           
    if(consumoAgua >1000){
      value = consumoAgua*0.80;
    }
    System.out.println("El coste de tu consumo es: "+value);
   
    }

}
```

Espero haber ayudado.